# Html.pagedListPager possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore, pagedlist

I am new to mvc and I am converting webforms to sitecore 8. I wanted to use pagedlist library. My code is pretty straight forward. On submission it renders on the correct page but when the paging is clicked it is redirecting me to

```
    /api/sitecore/controller/action?parameters
```

out of the current layout. I've been looking around for 2 days now.

```
       @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>  Url.Action("Display",
    new {page, sortorder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, filteroption = ViewBag.CurrentFilter}))
```

Is there any other way or any sitecore equivalent?

I've looked into speak.mvc config and commented it..And it still appends that /api/sitecore/

Thank you in advance

same topic here [Razor MVC partialview pagination url action, How to define specified url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467064/razor-mvc-partialview-pagination-url-action-how-to-define-specified-url)

But no answer and his question is not clear.

Comment: I really hope someone can help me on this..for the mean time..I'm using a jquery to replace the appended api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}

Answer (score 0):

I've answered the question on the other topic: [Razor MVC partialview pagination url action, How to define specified url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467064/razor-mvc-partialview-pagination-url-action-how-to-define-specified-url). I believe that this will also help you.

> Even though it has been a while this question is asked, it may be useful for those who are still having an issue with the generated pagination URL's. What you are getting is the default route. To solve it, you can add a custom route and point to it in the code @Html.PagedListPager.
>
> But in your case the following will do the trick:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => 
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item) + "?page=" + page)
```

> The part LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item) will get the URL of the current item. This way you will get "Aboutus.aspx?page=2" URL as expected.